# Search cursor skipping every other row

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, search

I am trying accomplish something which should be fairly straight forward. I am trying to merge snowfall events within 4 hours into a single event so. The end of the entire event, and the name of the weather station are written to another table. I am still learning Python, and I'm not an expert by any means.

In my code I calculate the time difference between the end of the previous snow event and the start of the next using Unix (epoch) time format. If the start of the next snow event is more than 4 hours (14400 seconds), the row is inserted into another table.

I am using a combination of a SearchCursor and an InsertCursor to do this. The SearchCursor looks at the next Event Start and compares it to the previous Event End. If the delta is equal to or more than 14400 seconds, the row is copied to another table using an insert cursor.

The SearchCursor begins skipping every other row after the first iteration. The first event is copied properly. The rows written to the Destination table are correct, however there are records between these which should also be copied as well. I used print statements to confirm that the SearchCursor is not reading the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc. lines.

I've included a screen capture of the Source and Destination tables below.

- In the Source table: the first three rows are more than 4 hours apart. These should be copied to the other table as separate snow events.
- In the Destination table, only the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. records are copied.

**Source Table**
[image: Source Table]

**Destination Table**
[image: Destination Table]

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
sourceTable = 'wthr_table'
sourceTableFields = ['snowstart_epoch','snowstop_epoch','snowstart','snowstop','station'] 
destTable = 'snow_events'
destTableFields = ['snowstart_epoch','snowstop_epoch','snowstart','snowstop','station']
iCur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(snowTable,snowTableFields) 

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sourceTable, sourceTableFields) as sCur:
    for row in sCur:
        try:
            nextRow = sCur.next()
            delta = int(nextRow[0]) - int(row[1])
            if delta >= 14400:
                iCur.insertRow(row)
            else:
                pass
        except StopIteration:
            print('No rows available')
        except:
            print('Something else went wrong')
    del iCur
    del row, sCur
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for row in sCur:` is iterating over the cursor, i.e. requesting the next item.

Then below that, you request the next item *again* by using `sCur.next()`, thus advancing the original iterator.

So the original `for` loop is going to see every other item.

Instead, you'll want to only use the `for` loop, and simply keep track of the row that it returned on the previous iteration.  Something along these lines:

```py
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sourceTable, sourceTableFields) as sCur:
    previous_row = None
    for current_row in sCur:
        if previous_row is not None:
            delta = int(current_row[0]) - int(previous_row[1])
            if delta >= 14400:
                iCur.insertRow(row)
        previous_row = current_row
```

Additionally, it's bad practice to use a bare `except` statement.  If you're seeing some error, you need to know specifically what happened so you can correct it.  That may be masking other issues in this case.  Generally you should only ever `except SomeSpecificExceptionThatYouActuallyExpect`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I see the issue now. I appreciate the detailed explanation. Your advice worked perfectly!